# Displaying PHP success and fail messages with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What went wrong in this code? I ready many post here on this issue but can't fix my error. I have the following.

**HTML Code**

```
    <div id="successMessage" style="display:none;"> It worked </div>
    <div id="failMessage" style="display:none;"> It failed </div>

    <div container>
          <div class="modal">
            <form>
             ....
            </form>
          </div>
    </div>
```

**PHP Code**

```
if(!$stmnt->execute()){
            echo "Failed!"; 

        }else{
            echo "Inserted";
        }
```

**AJAX Code**

```
   success: function(data){
    viewData();
    if (data=="Failed!") { 
        console.log(data);
        $("#failMessage").show();

        } else if(data=="Inserted"){
            console.log(data); 
            $("#successMessage").show();
        }
    }
```

**Problem:** I would like to display the error in the page not in console. I want to inform the user. Why is it not working with `$("#successMessage").show();`?

**PS:** I am using Bootstrap. Also how can I show my messages using one(1) `div="msg"` tag?

Comment: You are doing "echo", you're not actually returning anything. Plus, your "else" is wrong... change it to `else if ( data === 'Inserted')`

Comment: @Canastro How do I return it?

Comment: @Canastro But on issue of returning, why it is showing in console if I print it using `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @Giovanrich Because that success message will always execute even if it fails. That success message is declared outside the else statement. Check my answer to get the proper way of writing the statement.

Comment: @Ayush I changed but still not showing

Comment: echo "Failed!"; you are giveing this response and checking data=="Failed", so it will not match Fail condition. "!" mark is missing.

Comment: @Giovanrich Can you add the complete ajax call. You have just added the success part.

Comment: @VinayPandya I corrected that but still not showing

Comment: in success function first console.log(data) and see what is actually you are getting.

Comment: @VinayPandya Yes I did that, it is printing `Insertedphp` from php, I mean I tweaked that insert to see which one is being printed

Comment: see what you did in question else{data=="Inserted"}; its  {} please remove it and add ().

Comment: @VinayPandya Yes in my code I did, but on the post it would make comments made towrds tht useless

Comment: so please edit your question add your original code here so we can find errors. these way we won't be able to help. bcz your code already have so many typo. please edit your question.

Comment: @VinayPandya Okay, let me do so

Comment: instead of .show() try this $('#id').css("display","block"); may be this can help.

Comment: @VinayPandya Still not showing

Comment: @Giovanrich please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/dcbm9v83/ i have made one demo its working fine for me. maybe you are doing something wrong

Comment: @VinayPandya  Okay, thanks Let me get on to that

Answer (score 1):

Found a mistake in your code

PHP Code

```
   if(!$stmnt->execute()){
        echo "Failed!"; // Check the exclamation mark

    }else{
        echo "Inserted";
    }
```

AJAX Code

```
success: function(data){
        viewData();
        $('#addData').modal('hide');//close the modal.
        if (data=="Failed!") { // Add an exclamation mark to correct code
            $("#failMessage").show();
            //console.log(data); is showing message from PHP
        } else if (data=="Inserted") { // Change this else to else if
            $("#successMessage").show();
            //console.log(data); is showing message from PHP
       }
```

Change "`Failed`" in ajax to "`Failed!`". Also, change the `else` to correct format of `else if`

Comment: @Giovanrich What output are you getting when PHP is echoing success ??

Comment: It is inserting into DB that is when it must echo `success`